# Database Design and asp.net Model

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, extjs

I have two database table! both of them have columns with same name! and that case me a problem in asp.net model when i have two model for these two tables in the same form 
when ever I edit a record it added a ","!

let say TableA

```
       TableA                         TableB
          colA                          colC 
          colB                          colV  
          Name                          Name  
          Email                         Email
          Tele                          colT
          Note
```

in my ASP.net form as part of GridPanel1

```
 <Store>
                 <ext:Store
                     ID="AStore"
                     runat="server"
                     OnReadData="AStore_Refresh">
                     <Model>
                         <ext:Model ID="Model1" runat="server" IDProperty="colA">
                             <Fields>
                                 <ext:ModelField Name="colA" />
                                 <ext:ModelField Name="colB" />
                                 <ext:ModelField Name="Name" />
                                 <ext:ModelField Name="Email" />
                                 <ext:ModelField Name="Tele" />
                                 <ext:ModelField Name="Note" />
                               </Fields>
                         </ext:Model>
                     </Model>
                 </ext:Store>
             </Store>
```

GridPanel2 in the same Asp.Net form

```
 <Store>
                 <ext:Store
                     ID="BStore"
                     runat="server"
                     OnReadData="BStore_Refresh">
                     <Model>
                         <ext:Model ID="Model2" runat="server" IDProperty="colC">
                             <Fields>
                                 <ext:ModelField Name="colC" />
                                 <ext:ModelField Name="colV" />
                                 <ext:ModelField Name="Name" />
                                 <ext:ModelField Name="Email" />
                                 <ext:ModelField Name="colT" />
                               </Fields>
                         </ext:Model>
                     </Model>
                 </ext:Store>
             </Store>
```

my FormPanel

```
 <ext:TextField ID="colAtxt" runat="server" FieldLabel="colA:" Name="colA" />
                         <ext:TextField ID="colBtxt" runat="server" FieldLabel="colB:" Name="colB" />
                         <ext:TextField ID="Nametxt" runat="server" FieldLabel="Name:" Name="Name" />
                         <ext:TextField ID="Emailtxt" runat="server" FieldLabel="Email:" Name="Email" />
                         <ext:TextField ID="Teletxt" runat="server" FieldLabel="Telephone:" Name="Tele" />
                         <ext:TextField ID="Notetxt" runat="server" FieldLabel="Note:" Name="Note" />v
```

save function in server side

```
 TableA updatedrecord= db.TableA.SingleOrDefault(s => s.colA == id);
            updatedrecord.colB = colBtxt.Text;
            updatedrecord.Name = Nametxt.Text.ToString().Trim();
            updatedrecord.Email = Emailtxt.Text;
            updatedrecord.Tele = Teletxt.Text;
            updatedrecord.Note= Notetxt.Text;
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Output when ever I update a recored it added "," to the name and email
like if the name is : "kavin" it save it in database as ",kavin"
WHat is the problem is it a bad database stractured?

Comment: Where is your edit portion of the code?

Comment: I edit my post and added save function!!

Comment: did you try to change store2 name and email model field name

Comment: I try to change it in the code above! then it wont display any data from database! Is there any other way to change it? or do i have to change it in DataModel.edmx??

Comment: It seems that ASP.NET combines values from fields with same name and added a comma! dose anyone know about that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used Framework entity, and one of the entity futures are combining data from more than one table! and that is why the comma! so to solve this problem i changed to use Linq to SQL instead of using Entity framwork!

to read more about the different between Linq to SQL and Entitiy Framwork

http://jinaldesai.net/linq-to-sql-vs-entity-framework/